# Can't seem to listen for UncaughtErrorEvent for SubApplication loaded by SWFLoader

Tags: flash, apache-flex, swfloader, uncaught-exception, subapplication

I have a main Flex Application ('A.swf') loading a SubApplication (defined in' B.swf') via a SWFLoader and I need to listen for UncaughtErrorEvent from the SubApplication. I'm not able to get my event listeners to be called when I throw an error from within the SubApp ('B.swf').

After reading the asDoc for UncaughtErrorEvent and UncaughtErrorEvents I have added an event listener to A.swf's loaderInfo (The 'outter' main app) and also to B.swf's loaderInfo (though the Docs say not to do it here it is part of the event sequence in the capture and bubble phase...) as well as the SWFLoader internal FlexLoader.uncaughtErrorEvent (per Docs) like so:

```
swfLoader.content.loaderInfo.loader.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, uncaughtErrorFunction );
```

The event listener setup on the Loader.uncaughtErrorEvents is not firing when SubApplication in B.swf throws an error. Instead the listener on the main app's (A.swf) loaderInfo fires. Moreover, the event recieved by A.swf's loaderInfo has an eventphase equal to 'EventPhase.AT_TARGET' which the asDoc says should only be dispatched in the capture and bubble phases.

Am I not doing this correctly? Any thoughts or suggestions?

'A.swf' and 'B.swf' both compiled with Flex SDK 4.1, Flash Player 10.1. Browser is FireFox running Flash debug player 10.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that setting the SDK libraries to merge into the code for both A.swf and B.swf allows the UnCaughtErrorEvents to dispatch in the correct way.

It doesn't dispatch when using MX based Flex Applications with the SDK libraries linked via Shared Runtime Libraries (the default in Flash Builder).

Moreover, it will also work with pure SPARK Flex Applications with RSL or merged into code.

See the discussion here: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3835326

Submitted Flex Bug here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-30996
For examples see attachments on submitted bug.

Answer (score 0):

See Alex Harui's blog post, that should work.
http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2011/04/catching-uncaughterror-in-flex-modules.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Alex states "This is due to the fact that Modules dereference the module SWF’s loaderInfo right away, in order to make unloading modules automatic." While ModuleLoader and SWFLoader both deep under the hood use a flash.display.Loader to do the work, SubApplications unlike modules don't dereference the loaded SWF's loaderInfo.

I am able to attach my event listener at the appropriate time (after applicationComplete event from loaded SubApplication) and I can see it attached in the debugger, but it isn't being called.